# Keycloak: Use custom SPI provider for EmailTemplateProvider

Tags: keycloak

I did a custom implementation for Keycloak EmailTemplateProvider interface. However, after setting the new implementation as the default-provider for emailTemplate it seems that not all the new code is taken into consideration.

I managed to override methods from EmailTemplateProvider as setRealm, setAttribute, but I couldn't manage to override send email methods. For example, the code written for the **sendEvent** method is not taken into consideration and the old implementation seems to be used.

Could you please, help me understand, why for some methods the default implementation is still used?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How did you set your implementation as the default implementation? I had to write a custom **EmailTemplateProvider** to stop creating templates & sending emails from keycloak and use our own email service for both purposes.

I set my implementation as the default by returning `"freemarker"` as the id from `setId` method of **EmailTemplateProviderFactory** and `"default"` from **EmailSenderProviderFactory**. I read the docs of Keycloak on how to install/launch your custom provider but none of that worked for me for some reason.

Also, make sure that you have a folder named **services** (inside **META-INF** folder) containing file **org.keycloak.email.EmailTemplateProviderFactory** which should contain where to import your custom provider from, from your code. If you are overriding keycloak's email sender as well (just like me), add one more file for **EmailSenderProviderFactory**.

Make sure you have used `@Override` annotation. My pom.xml file includes keycloak-model-jpa as the dependency with maven 11 as compiler with keycloak version 20.0.1.

Have a look at this repo, where the code for the default providers is written: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/main/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/email